# make: python2.5-config: command not found error on TinyOS

Tags: python

I'm currently using Windows 7 with Cygwin and TinyOS. I tried running a Blink application using TOSSIM. However, I keep getting errors as below:

```
$make micaz sim
mkdir -p simbuild/micaz
make: python2.5-config: Command not found
make: python2.5-config: Command not found
make: python2.5-config: Command not found
```

I checked few sites that suggested to change the PYTHON_VERSION in 'sim.extra', 'sim-sf.extra' and 'sim-fast.extra' files and to add CFLAGS line += -I/usr/include/python2.5 in 'sim.extra'. 
The python version that I'm currently using is 2.5.1. I changed the PYTHON_VERSION in these files to 2.5 and added the CFLAGS line. Then, I tried again but ended up with the same errors again and again. Can anyone help me? Thank you. :)

Comment: Did you try installing the Python development package?

Comment: I installed cygwin using manual installation using RPM packages. During the installation, the packages installed are Misc. I'm guessing Python was installed but I'm not sure of the development package. I'm sorry if I sound confused or shallow. I'm still very new to TinyOS.

Comment: I've never looked at it at all, so I can't really help you any beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

This problem had been explained on this website : https://www.blogkafem.net/2017/09/tinyos-python-config-ve-pythonh-sorunu.html

But, I this website not English. So, I will try to translate briefly the solution for you.

Install python version : 2.7

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python-gevent
```

Then, You should update python path from TinyOS configuration :
(you should care last line)

```
export TOSROOT="/opt/tinyos"
export TOSDIR="$TOSROOT/tos"
export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:$TOSROOT/support/sdk/java/tinyos.jar
export MAKERULES="$TOSROOT/support/make/Makerules"
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$TOSROOT/support/sdk/python:PYTHONPATH
echo "setting up TinyOS on source path $TOSROOT"
export CPATH=:/usr/include/python2.7/
```

Lastly, open to "sim.extra" file. If you are using linux, you can write this command : "sim.extra"

and, update **PYTHON_VERSION** line, like this :

```
PYTHON_VERSION ?= $(shell python --version 3>&1 | sed 's/Python 2\.\([0-9]\)\.[0-9]+\{0,1\}/2.\1/')
```